# Digital dictionaries with sound for French learners

Tags: pronunciation, online-learning, french, dictionary

I had been using Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English on a computer app. It was a great experience working with a dictionary that gives you pronunciations, examples with sound, thesaurus, and many more. I am wondering if there is a similar (digital) dictionary for French?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*, but the free online dictionaries on the [*Larousse*](https://www.larousse.fr) website may be useful. In particular:

- The monolingual French dictionary has a sample pronunciation of [the canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(morphology)) and links to synonyms. It does also have examples of usage, but there is no audio sample for those.
- The [bilingual dictionaries](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/) have sample pronunciations of the canonical form and of the examples used to illustrate usage.

Larousse has also published some phone apps. However, those are not free, and I have no idea what features are available as I have never used them.